# How do I make this program loop indefinitely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, infinite-loop

I want to loop this code indefinitely (until the user kills it) from the very beginning to the end, so I won't have to keep rerunning it. Is there anyway to make this possible? I would appreciate the help greatly.The program should restart itself after the user inputs "done" (and its printed all the details.)

```
print ("Input done when finished")
print ("Input thresholds")

maximumnum = int(input("Input maximum number: "))
minimumnum = int(input("Input minimum number: "))


minimum = None
maximum = None

while True:
    inp =input("Enter a number: ")
    if inp == "done": 
        break

    try:
        num = float(inp)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
        continue  

    ## ---- Additional Check ---- ##
    if num > maximumnum:
        print('Number greater the maximum allowed range')
        break

    if num < minimumnum:
    print('Number smaller the maximum allowed range')
    break        
    ## -------------------------- ##                  

    if minimum is None or num < minimum:
        minimum = num

    if maximum is None or num > maximum:
        maximum = num

print ("Maximum:", maximum)
print ("Minimum:", minimum)
print ("Try again")
```

Comment: You are already looping it indefinitely? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Put another `while playing` around your entire program, and use a variable to define when to end.
@MikeTung: Once the program breaks (due to num > maximumnum or so), the last lines get printed and it ends.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap the whole script in another while True? To stop, the user must kill the running process.

```
while True:
    print ("Input done when finished")
    print ("Input thresholds")

    maximumnum = int(input("Input maximum number: "))
    minimumnum = int(input("Input minimum number: "))


    minimum = None
    maximum = None

    while True:
        inp =input("Enter a number: ")
        if inp == "done": 
            break

        try:
            num = float(inp)
        except:
            print ("Invalid input")
            continue  

        ## ---- Additional Check ---- ##
        if num > maximumnum:
            print('Number greater the maximum allowed range')
            break

        if num < minimumnum:
        print('Number smaller the maximum allowed range')
        break        
        ## -------------------------- ##                  

        if minimum is None or num < minimum:
            minimum = num

        if maximum is None or num > maximum:
            maximum = num

    print ("Maximum:", maximum)
    print ("Minimum:", minimum)
    print ("Try again")
```

Comment: The break only breaks out of the inner while True loop, not the outer loop.

Comment: @Martin exactly so then the print statements are executed and the script is run again. That is the expected behavior after all

Comment: This solves the problem that the problem when it comes to the loop but undermines the program's purpose. The program restarts itself after a single input but it's meant to do so after the user inputs "done" (and its printed all the details.)

Answer (score 0):

I frequently use a paradigm such as this to accomplish a "loop until I say so" 
sort of thing.

```
class UserKilledException(KeyboardInterrupt):
     pass

try:
    while True:
        #do stuff
except UserKilledException:
    #do cleanup here
```

Just have your code throw a `UserKilledException` whenever the user decides to close the application somehow.  If it's a cli application then `KeyboardInterrupt` will do the trick.

Comment: Hi Scott - That is interesting approach, however, I think if user try to kill the program (as requested in question), then your code would catch the exception, but handle that which doesn't allow user to terminate the execution using keyboard interrupt (like ctrl + c). I believe question is more simple, they just want to run the code in infinite loop including asking the question part.

Comment: In accordance with Ali, I'd upvote this if you got rid of the pass statement and added a comment saying "# do cleanup here". Then it becomes an elegant approach because it allows the user to interrupt but gives the application an opportunity to do some housekeeping.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap this on method and run that in infinite loop. Please try following:

```
def process_input(maximumnum, minimumnum):
    minimum = None
    maximum = None

    while True:
        inp =input("Enter a number: ")
        if inp == "done":
            break

        try:
            num = float(inp)
        except:
            print("Invalid input")
            continue

            ## ---- Additional Check ---- ##
        if num > maximumnum:
            print('Number greater the maximum allowed range')
            break

        if num < minimumnum:
            print('Number smaller the maximum allowed range')
        break
        ## -------------------------- ##                  

        if minimum is None or num < minimum:
            minimum = num

        if maximum is None or num > maximum:
            maximum = num

    return minimum, maximum


def main():
    print("Input done when finished")
    print("Input thresholds")

    maximumnum = int(input("Input maximum number: "))
    minimumnum = int(input("Input minimum number: "))

    minimum, maximum = process_input(maximumnum, minimumnum)

    print("Maximum:", maximum)
    print("Minimum:", minimum)
    print("Try again")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solves the problem that the problem when it comes to the loop but undermines the program's purpose. The program restarts itself after a single input but it's meant to do so after the user inputs "done" (and its printed all the details.)

Comment: Hi Cherie - The above is same as your original code only difference is that I organized it by using methods and only added infinite loop to the code. If I may ask (and possible) would you mind if you share your requirements for this code. That would make it easier to assist you with the code.